# Why does my button go up when the keyboard appears in react native? button view position is absolute?

Tags: react-native

Here are my code:

[image]

[image]

This is in android.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Folder **Android** > **app** > **src** > **main** > **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
  -------------
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
  -------------
</activity>
```

Change to :

```
<activity
  -------------
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
  -------------
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically Your keyboard is not avoiding your view or component. so you'll have to wrap your Component in

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView>
    //your component
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

additionally you can use props of keyboard avoiding view

Comment: i have tried this, but it's doesn't work for me